# Python 3 Joining elements of different strings in a List

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a program that reads over separate lines in a text file to create a staff record in a list which is stored like `name:email:number` in a list.

I am able to print the list and I am able to extract the email addresses. This is the code I have so far:

```
def testEmail(staffList) :
    print(staffList)
    for emails in staffList :
        print(str(emails.getEmail()))
```

which prints

```
[Person1:email1@bla.co.uk:12345678911, Person2:email2@bla.com:98765432198]
email1@bla.co.uk
email2@bla.com
```

I would like to print the extracted email addresses to the screen like `email1@bla.co.uk;email2@bla.com`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect all addresses in a list first and then join them by your separation character:

```
addresses = []
for emails in staffList:
    addresses.append(str(emails.getEmail()))
print(';'.join(addresses))
```

Or in short:

```
print(';'.join(str(emails.getEmail()) for emails in staffList))
```